# I wonder why I have always failed to add screenshot-tool ppa ? Please help

Tags: screenshot

[image: every time I added a screenshot-tool PPA, always fail?]

Every time I would install the screenshot tool and add PPA, always fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `screenshot-tool` was moved to the elementary's Launchpad, so what you should execute if you want the latest version is:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade screenshot-tool
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:elementary-os/daily
```

The installation instructions *are* outdated. I hope that @Ravan is going to manage to get them fixed by contacting Fabio.

Comment: good information +1 =)

Answer (score 2):

After a little research and with the help of my Ask Ubuntu friends,

It is clear that there is **no PPA** with that name.(at present)

The [OP](https://launchpad.net/~fabiozaramella) might have *hidden/deleted* the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/screenshot-tool).

After *compile* (by my [AU friend](https://askubuntu.com/users/367165/a-b))

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fabiozaramella/screenshot-tool 
[sudo] password for : 
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~fabiozaramella/ubuntu/screenshot-tool'. 
The user named '~fabiozaramella' has no PPA named 'ubuntu/screenshot-tool'
```

<sub>I have sent a mail to the  fabiozaramella, waiting for reply</sub>

Comment: -1, why? please re-read the question. the OP asking about his error message, I gave clarity for that--

Answer (score 1):

This could be coused by a lot of things.

- Your firewall might be blocking it (not really likely)
- You might have no internet connection
- The repository might be deleted or renamed (or it might just not exists)