# Curious about my apt-get update returns

Tags: pantheon-terminal, updates, sources

So I try to `apt-get update` on the regular when I am working in Terminal. Recently I have been running said command and getting a few errors at the end.  Doesn't seem to effect my box to much of an extent but, how can I go about troubleshooting all of these issues that are being returned? See below:

```
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://elementary OS 0.3.1 _Freya_ - Stable amd64 (20150903)/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://elementary OS 0.3.1 _Freya_ - Stable amd64 (20150903)/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://elementary OS 0.3.1 _Freya_ - Stable amd64 (20150903)/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://elementary OS 0.3.1 _Freya_ - Stable amd64 (20150903)/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W: Failed to fetch htp://ppa.launchpad.net/ronmi/wallbox/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch htp://ppa.launchpad.net/ronmi/wallbox/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch htp://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch htp://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: No misspelt, I think because of low rep, OP might skipped one `t` in `http`

Comment: Spot on haha very intuitive

Comment: Have you satisfied with my answer? ;P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution for your specific question**:

Open *Software & Updates*  -- > other software tab:

- Uncheck cd rom option.
- You have added two unsupported PPA's:

  [ppa:ronmi/wallbox](https://launchpad.net/%7Eronmi/+archive/ubuntu/wallbox) and

  [ppa:versable/elementary-update](https://launchpad.net/%7Eversable/+archive/ubuntu/elementary-update).

  Removing those two will solve 404 error.

  [image: Imgur]

---

More information (for your *curiosity* ;))

**Failed to fetch cdrom....**:

The reason for this error is that cdrom has been included as one of the the sources here.

And to fix this issue, we need to remove this from the list of software sources.

[What are 404 errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404):

> The 404 or Not Found error message is an HTTP standard response code indicating that the client was able to communicate with a given server, but the server could not find what was requested.
>
> The web site hosting server will typically generate a "404 Not Found" web page when a user attempts to follow a broken or dead link;

**Reasons for these errors**:

- A user has enabled a PPA software-source that **no longer exists**
- A user has manually typed in a new software source incorrectly
- A PPA was added, but **the maintainer has subsequently deleted** some/all of the PPA (like [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/2922/2708))

**To eleminate these errors**:

Open software & updates -- > other software tab:

- To remove `Failed to fetch cdrom://` error mesage: uncheck CD-ROM option.

  [image: Imgur]
- To remove 404 errors:

  - If the error is due to a PPA - usually **unticking** the similarly named PPA with the URL shown in the error message will resolve this.
  - If the 404 error was due to an additional repository that has been added to `/etc/apt/sources.list` then its easier to add `#` character to the start of the line to comment out the offending repository

---

Comment: Alright this worked for most of the problems I was having with my returns.  I have tried going into the source.list file and commenting a few lines but I have realized another problem with my box.  A while ago I kind of screwed the pooch on my main Admin account; long story short I just got stuck  into a log in loop.  I created a new account with sudo privs.  Now the problem is I can't edit any of these files because they don't belong to me.  How do I go about changing ownership of files and or completely removing the original admin account seeing as I don't use it anymore?

Comment: @ZeDD fine, it sounds like your problem can be answerable, but sorry, please open a new question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the first line of each of them. `Failed to fetch cdrom://` and `Failed to fetch htp://ppa.launchpad.net`. It means that apt is looking for updates at these URLs, but it's not able to get them for some reason.

The first 4 are looking for a CD and you probably don't have that CD mounted.

The last 4 are PPAs you've installed and it looks like the URL is misspelled.

You can manage your software sources by:

1. open up the applications menu and search for "Software & Updates"
2. Select the "Other" tab
3. Edit, Add, or Remove, or uncheck the offending sources

Comment: I had to remove a t in the http to be able to post this question.